# ffmpeg -flags2 +export_mvs ... to in *.txt

Tags: microsoft-excel, video, ffmpeg

I'm doing research and practices on ffmpeg, I could see the motion vectors on a video between frames through the command "fFmpeg - flags2 + export_mvs ...".
Is it possible to record the change of coordinates of motion vectores between two frames on a .txt or excel file in order to operate it in another job?
can you help me on this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this example file from FFmpeg [extract_mvs.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/extract_mvs.c). You can find it in your FFmpeg source directory, under *doc/examples*. After compiling, you can use it as `./extract_mvs <video>` to print the information regarding each motion vector. You can re-direct the output a .txt file by: `./extract_mvs <video> > output.txt`. Unfortunately, this does not give your very detailed information (motion vectors of macroblock partitions and submacroblocks, reference picture index, number of reference pictures, etc.) but I think there are ways to extract more detailed information as well.